# how to solve "Unable to load persistent store at URL " error?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, sharing

My application crashes when i want to share a post on facebook by selecting iOS simulator 5.0 i don t know how to solve this problem here is my log message

```
2012-12-28 14:55:19.175 SendQuote[2029:3603] Unable to load persistent store at URL 'file://localhost/Users/winsolutions/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "5232202C-AF68-41AA-905F-5B023F1954D4";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
})
```

and at the end i get this log message

```
2012-12-28 14:55:33.822 SendQuote[2029:c07] -[CFXPreferencesSearchListSource tryLock]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80f5960
2012-12-28 14:55:33.938 SendQuote[2029:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CFXPreferencesSearchListSource tryLock]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80f5960'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183d052 0x162cd0a 0x183eced 0x17a3f00 0x17a3ce2 0x79c1770 0x1150a39 0x1808885 0x18087a8 0x10951aa 0x7a2169 0x7aa8bd 0x7ab1f8 0x79eaa9 0x234bfa9 0x18111c5 0x1776022 0x177490a 0x1773db4 0x1773ccb 0x234a879 0x234a93e 0x79ca9b 0x2b5a 0x2a65)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Are u getting this error on simulator?

Comment: just delete the app from simulator/device then run  it again will work.You must have changed the schema of your core data.

Comment: yep its working....but i have login my facebook acount but on permission page it sends me back to login ,,,what to do now???

Comment: on my okay button it pull me back to login

Comment: just anser i will accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Reset the simulator from **iOS Simulator => Reset Content and Settings**...

and here you reset the simulator so whole session and cache data are remove from the **iPhone Simulator Directory** so Re-enter and then use the app as routine..